# Is Chromium source code really 940 megabytes?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, source-code

I want to download the latest source of Chromium so I can modify it a bit and compile it. I went through all the instructions and was pointed to a tarball to download, but it's 940 megabytes.

1. How can the source code for Chromium be 940MB?
2. If that's wrong file, can someone point me to latest Chromium source code?

Comment: There's Chromium (the browser) and Chromium OS (the operating system).  Are you downloading the right one?

Comment: chromium.r76198.tgz - 

i think im dling the rite one :/

Comment: if only you knew how bad things would get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the sources from the link available over [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code#TOC-Check-out-the-sources)

The linked page mentions:

> If you only want to look at the source code on your own machine, you'll need **at least 1.6 GB** of hard drive space available.

so yes, the tarball size seems appropriate.

Comment: You missed the best part of that line: *…you'll need at least 1.6 GB of hard drive space available. (Somewhat less for Linux, since it already has some of the dependencies installed.) If you want to build it, you will need just under **10 GB** of space, including all the object files and executables.*!

Comment: @Syntech indeed!